# What other protocols can run over the Link Layer besides IP protocol?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ipv6, tcpip, ipv4

I am reading about ARP [here](http://www.omnisecu.com/tcpip/address-resolution-protocol-arp.php) and it says

"Each protocol is assigned a number used in this field. IPv4 is 2048 (0x0800 in Hexa)."

What are other alternatives to IPv4 and IPv6 as protocols to be run over the Link Layer protocol.

Comment: virtual lan for instance. And most tunneling.

Comment: Here is a starting point: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5342#appendix-B

Comment: Actually that lists many Ethertypes not just those using ARP. On second reading of your question I realize that you are only asking for those which makes use of ARP. In that case I don't know any protocol other than IPv4. And there is a misunderstanding in your question, since IPv6 doesn't use ARP. Instead IPv6 uses neighbor discovery, which is very similar to ARP but uses ICMPv6 packets rather than ARP packets.

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml

Answer (score 3):

AppleTalk over Ethernet uses AARP which is very similar in structure.

Answer (score 0):

DECNET is another non-ip protocol. See [HECNET](http://www.update.uu.se/~bqt/hecnet.html) if you run a real or simulated OpenVMS system.

Comment: Wikipedia says DECNET was [not using ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECnet). (The question is about the protocols in ARP, not about non-IP protocols).

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.